# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. <template> \endtemplate Please help

Tags: tables, alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of TMGS with MGS and MGS\_B for Example 5.1, where $\mu=4$}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{n}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{TMGS}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{MGS [34]}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{MGS\_B[21]}} \\ \cline{3-11} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \textbf{IT} & \textbf{CPT} & \textbf{RES} & \textbf{IT} & \textbf{CPT} & \textbf{RES} & \textbf{IT} & \textbf{CPT} & \textbf{RES} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{100$\times$100} & & 11 & 0.024 & $8.2911 \times 10^{-6}$ & 21 & 0.035 & $8.2911 \times 10^{-6}$ & 24 & 0.068 & $6.9563 \times 10^{-6}$ \\
 & & 200$\times$200 & 12 & 0.0981 & $3.6744 \times 10^{-6}$ & 22 & 0.171 & $8.4217 \times 10^{-6}$ & 25 & 0.283 & $7.7193 \times 10^{-6}$ \\
 & & 300$\times$300 & 12 & 0.395 & $5.5794 \times 10^{-6}$ & 23 & 0.542 & $5.5794 \times 10^{-6}$ & 26 & 0.741 & $5.1092 \times 10^{-6}$ \\
 & & 400$\times$400 & 12 & 0.714 & $7.4843 \times 10^{-6}$ & 23 & 1.034 & $7.4843 \times 10^{-6}$ & 26 & 1.418 & $6.8537 \times 10^{-6}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your table specification `{|c|c...}` has defined 10 columns.  Your rows have 11 to 15 columns, so the extra `&` gets converted to `\\ ` so that TeX can try to recover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is supposed to have 10 columns. However, you appear to have lost track of how to format the first column, and as a result the table actually has 12 columns; that's what's causing the (admittedly cryptic) "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" error messages. Redesigning the first column can bring the column count back down to 10; see the first table in the following screenshot for a way to achieve this.

I would further like to recommend that you load the `siunitx` package and employ its `S` column type to format the contents of columns 4, 7, and 10. That way, you could enter the "scientific" numbers as `8.2911e-6` instead of as `$8.2911 \times 10^{-6}$`, etc and let LaTeX do the formatting job for you. Applying this approach also helps declutter the input because all those `$` tokens are no longer needed to switch into and out of inline math mode.

A separate thought: The table's look is anything but open and inviting. Do get rid of all vertical lines and employ the macros of the `booktabs` package to generate more generously spaced horizontal lines. I would also argue that there's no real need to bold-face the header cells. The second table shown in the following screenshot implements these ideas. Observe that the resulting table not only has a more open "look", as desired -- it's always slightly less wide.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}   % '\extrarowheight' param., '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{siunitx} % 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic math mode
\usepackage{booktabs} % for line-drawing macros in second table

\begin{document}

% first table
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of TMGS with MGS and MGS\_B for Example 5.1, where $\mu=4$}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{| C | *{3}{ c | c | S[table-format=1.4e-1] |} }
\hline
\textbf{n} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{TMGS}} 
           & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{MGS [34]}} 
           & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{MGS\_B [21]}}\\ 
\cline{2-10} 
 & \textbf{IT} & \textbf{CPT} & {\textbf{RES}} 
 & \textbf{IT} & \textbf{CPT} & {\textbf{RES}} 
 & \textbf{IT} & \textbf{CPT} & {\textbf{RES}} \\ 
\hline
100\times100 & 11 & 0.024 & 8.2911e-6 & 21 & 0.035 & 8.2911e-6 & 24 & 0.068 & 6.9563e-6 \\
200\times200 & 12 & 0.098 & 3.6744e-6 & 22 & 0.171 & 8.4217e-6 & 25 & 0.283 & 7.7193e-6 \\
300\times300 & 12 & 0.395 & 5.5794e-6 & 23 & 0.542 & 5.5794e-6 & 26 & 0.741 & 5.1092e-6 \\
400\times400 & 12 & 0.714 & 7.4843e-6 & 23 & 1.034 & 7.4843e-6 & 26 & 1.418 & 6.8537e-6 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


% second table
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Same table as before, but with a more open look}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} C *{3}{ c c S[table-format=1.4e-1] } @{}}
\toprule
n & \multicolumn{3}{c}{TMGS} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{MGS [34]} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{MGS\_B [21]} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10} 
 & IT & CPT & {RES} & IT & CPT & {RES} & IT & CPT & {RES} \\ 
\midrule
100\times100 & 11 & 0.024 & 8.2911e-6 & 21 & 0.035 & 8.2911e-6 & 24 & 0.068 & 6.9563e-6 \\
200\times200 & 12 & 0.098 & 3.6744e-6 & 22 & 0.171 & 8.4217e-6 & 25 & 0.283 & 7.7193e-6 \\
300\times300 & 12 & 0.395 & 5.5794e-6 & 23 & 0.542 & 5.5794e-6 & 26 & 0.741 & 5.1092e-6 \\
400\times400 & 12 & 0.714 & 7.4843e-6 & 23 & 1.034 & 7.4843e-6 & 26 & 1.418 & 6.8537e-6 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```